# HTML Escaping/Encoding in Javascript/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, encoding, escaping

I have multiple pages of html code saved into a database. I want a file to be able to flip through each of these pages without reloading.

I created a PHP file to pull all the pages into a database.

The page shows the first page and navigation buttons.

There is also javascript to put all the other pages into an array so I can quickly switch pages.

```
var pages = new Array();
<?php foreach ($coursePages as $page): ?>
    pages[pageCount] = "<?php echo ($page['body']) ?>";
    pageCount++;
<?php endforeach ?>
```

My problem is creating the javascript array. How can I escape the data from the echo properly so it can eventually change the page content using the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.navNext, .navPrevious').click(function({
        if ($(this).hasClass('navNext')) {
            page++;
            if (page > pageCount) {
                page = 0;
            }
        } else {
            page--;
            if (page < 0) {
                page = 0;
            }
        }

        $('.page').html(pages[page]);
    }))
});
```

Comment: May be it's better to render this pages to <div id="page1" class="pages hidden"> content </div> and than just switch divs visibiblity? $('.pages').hide();$('#page'+uid).show(); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime you send values dynamically from PHP to JavaScript, you can simply use json_encode(). It will always produce valid JavaScript and handle all data types. Example:

```
<script>
    var a = <?php echo json_encode($var)?>;
</script>
```

Comment: This was kind of where I was going but for some reason it didn't seem to work properly. I tried it again and now it is.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this function to escape js values:

```
function js_escape_string($str)
{
    $str = str_replace("\\", "\\\\", strval($str));
    $str = str_replace("'", "\\'", $str);
    $str = str_replace("\r", "\\r", $str);
    $str = str_replace("\n", "\\n", $str);
    $str = str_replace("\t", "\\t", $str);
    $str = str_replace("</script>", "</'+'script>", $str);
    return $str;
}
```

NOTE: use single quote ' around JS values, like:

```
<script>
var a = '<?php echo js_escape_string(....); ?>';
</script>
```